# Amount of single quotes when running dynamic SQL with variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am having a real hard time sorting out the number of `'` I should have within the following SQL statement:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @LetterID varchar(max) = 'c01as1'
set @sql = 
'SELECT fltr.tency_seq_no FROM OPENQUERY(loopback, 
    ''SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC BST.[LET].[LETTERBUILD] @LetterCode = 
        ''''\\SVR-QL4APPLIVE\QLSHAREPOINT\LETTERS\DATAFILES\
            '''+@LetterID+'''
        .csv''''
    WITH RESULT SETS (tency_seq_no VARCHAR(255))''
) AS fltr'
exec (@sql)
```

Current error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'c01as1'

Just to clarify, the error is referring to the `@LetterID` variable within the dynamic SQL , not when declaring the parameter

Print of @ SQL

```
SELECT fltr.tency_seq_no 
FROM OPENQUERY(loopback, 'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC BST.[LET].[LETTERBUILD] @LetterCode = ''\\SVR-QL4APPLIVE\QLSHAREPOINT\LETTERS\DATAFILES\'c01as1'.csv''
     WITH RESULT SETS (tency_seq_no VARCHAR(255));'
    ) AS fltr
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Whenever you are using dynamic sql you need to print/select your query before you execute it. It will highlight very quickly where the problems are.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, thank you for the suggestion, I have done a print sql and I can see the output (added to the OP). However this doesn't highlight to me where the issue is... Anything else you can suggest now seeing the printed sql?

Comment: Tip: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9352715/92546) answer for how to use the Parse feature in SSMS. You can cut'n'paste your dynamic SQL into a new tab and use Parse to validate the syntax,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error has got something to do with unwanted line breaks etc in the original code. Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @LetterID VARCHAR(MAX) = 'c01as1';

SET @sql = 'SELECT fltr.tency_seq_no FROM OPENQUERY(loopback, 
    ''SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC BST.[LET].[LETTERBUILD] @LetterCode = ''''\\SVR-QL4APPLIVE\QLSHAREPOINT\LETTERS\DATAFILES\'
           + @LetterID + '.csv''''
    WITH RESULT SETS (tency_seq_no VARCHAR(255))''
) AS fltr';

EXEC (@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this difficulty a few months ago, I created a function that would perform a double-up on the quotes for dynamic SQL.  Instead of searching the string manually each time for quotes needing to be doubled, this scalar function can perform this task. This can prevent potentially cluttering up the script when future modifications are performed, such as adding additional variables, as well as improving readability.

Function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_duplicateQuotes
    (@string varchar(max),
    @level int)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    /*Doubles-up quotation marks for nested dynamic SQL
      level can be set greater than 1 to add additional doubled-up quotes
      for further nested dynamic SQL*/

    /*Double up quotes*/
        set @string = REPLACE(@string, '''', REPLICATE('''', (@level) * 2))

    /*Return Value*/
        return @string
END
```

Dynamic SQL as follows:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @LetterID varchar(max) = 'c01as1'

set @SQL = 'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC BST.[LET].[LETTERBUILD] @LetterCode = 
              ''\\SVR-QL4APPLIVE\QLSHAREPOINT\LETTERS\DATAFILES\' + @LetterID + '.csv''
             WITH RESULT SETS (tency_seq_no VARCHAR(255));'

set @SQL = 'SELECT fltr.tency_seq_no FROM OPENQUERY(loopback,
        ''' + dbo.fn_duplicateQuotes(@SQL, 1) + '''
        ) AS fltr'

print @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

Print of @SQL returns:

```
SELECT fltr.tency_seq_no FROM OPENQUERY(loopback,
        'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC BST.[LET].[LETTERBUILD] @LetterCode = 
              ''\\SVR-QL4APPLIVE\QLSHAREPOINT\LETTERS\DATAFILES\c01as1.csv''
             WITH RESULT SETS (tency_seq_no VARCHAR(255));'
        ) AS fltr
```